# If $l$ is a logarithm function and $w^n(z)=z$, then $w(z)=e^{2\pi ik/n}e^{\frac{1}{n}l(z)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

This is an exercise from Remmert's, Theory of Complex Functions.

Show that if $l$ is a logarithm function in $G$ and $w: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and satisfies $w^n(z)=z$ for all $z \in G$, then $w(z)=e^{2\pi ik/n}e^{\frac{1}{n}l(z)}$ for all $z \in G$ and some $k \in \{0,1,...,n-1\}$

The proof I did is basically reproducing the proof of the $n$ different roots of unity.

**My attempt:**

Take $\xi_u = e^{2\pi iu/n}e^{\frac{1}{n}l(z)}$ with $u \in \{0,1,...,n-1\}$. Since ${\xi_u}{\xi_v}^{-1}=e^{2\pi i(\frac{u-v}{n})}$, then ${\xi_u}={\xi_v}$ if and only if $\frac{u-v}{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$. As $|u-v|<n$, then ${\xi_u}={\xi_v} \Leftrightarrow  u=v$. So $\xi_0, \xi_1, \ldots, \xi_{n-1}$ are all different. Since the polynomial $\xi^n-z=0$has at most $n$ different zeros, $\xi_0, \xi_1, \ldots, \xi_{n-1}$ are all possible options for $w(z)$.

I don't know if this is quite right, cause I didn't really use the fact that $w$ is a function, and more, a *continuous* function. I just assume the fact that if $w(z)=a$, then $a^n = z$, which I don't know if is right.

I appreciate any help or comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that $G\subseteq\mathbb C$ is a open simply-connected subset of the complex plane which doesn't contains $0$.
Then $\ell$ is holomorphic and satisfy $\ell'(z)=\frac 1z$ for each $z\in G$.
If there exists complexes $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\beta=\exp(\alpha)\in G$, then we can assume $\ell(\beta)=\alpha$.

Let define $f(z)=w(z)\exp(-\ell(z)/n)$ and $g(z)=f(z)^n$.
We have $g(z)=z\exp(-\ell(z))$ hence $g'(z)=0$ for each $z\in G$.
This implies $g$ constant on $G$.
Thus $g(z)=g(\beta)=1$.
Since $f(z)^n=1$ and $f$ is continuous, we have $f(z)=\exp(2\pi i k/n)$ for some fixed $k\in\mathbb N$ and this concludes the proof.

Comment: Thank you very much, very clear, I had been thinking about it several days. Just a little question, how can we conclude that $f(z)^n=1$ and $f$ continuous implies $f(z)=\exp(2\pi ik/n)$? I see it's clear but I don't know the argument.

Comment: The image $f(G)$ is connected by continuity of $f$ and it's contained in $Z=\{z\in\mathbb C:z^n=1\}$ which is discrete. Thus $f(G)$ consists of a point only.

Comment: Alternative proof: $G$ is disjoint union of $f^{-1}({z})$ for $z\in Z$; each $f^{-1}(z)$ is open and $G$ is connected thus $G=f^{-1}({z})$ for some $z\in Z$.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks.